# Incorrect icon size when imported to exe

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, icons

EDIT: Solved, (at least for the explorer) the problem was it keeps the old thumbs.db.

I have a png icon and I've created a 128px, 96px, 64px, 32px, 16px icon using several tools. But the result is always the same.. when I compile the exe using that icon and resize to max icon size, it stays to something like 32-48px. Anyone got the same issue? Also when I put the executable on RocketDock, it also gets small icon. The executable has all icons, I checked it with Resource Hacker. It's a strange issue, I just wanted to make my app with big icon so it can be used in dock applications and on users that use bigger icon sizes.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about. The Visual Studio icon is there just for test.

[image]

And also a RocketDock screenshot containing a shortcut to the icon and to the executable:

[image]

Comment: How are the icons layed out in your resource file?  As far as I know Explorer will use the first icon it finds (i.e. lowest resource number).  I think the standard practice is to create one .ico file with all the different resolution icons embedded in it; this way Explorer will choose the most appropriate one.

Comment: I have this same issue, and while I read that restarting the computer should fix it, it has not. Is there something else I need to do? I see a number of thumbs.db files, none of which have been changed recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [Axialis Icon Workshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/) successfully before, and it's even recommended in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx) MSDN article. Not free but the trial version should be enough for one-off shots. I'm not perfectly sure it will solve your problem but it should.

Comment: Thanks for the MSDN link, but it doesn't solves my problem. I used Icon Workshop to create 256, 128, 64, 32, 16 icon for my software and still the icon looks small.

Comment: I use the free version of Axialis and it does allow you to create all of the icon sizes in one file.