# Set application icon and window icon to Windows 7 friendly icon

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2010, icons

I've created a WPF project in Visual Studio 2010 using .net 4.0

I've created an icon with many different sizes and formats right from 16x16 4 bit BMP up to 256x256 24 bit BMP.  I set it as the program's icon in the property pages for the application, and as the window's icon in the icon propety on a WPF Window.

This works to a point.  The icon is displayed in all the expected location, however, it seems invariably to use one of th lower resolution images.  In the task bar it apperas to be using a 16x16 image.  In the folder if you view the exe file with it set to extra large icons it appears as a tiny image with lots of white space arround it, rather than choosing the large icon.  Even if I set it up with a 256x256 icon as the only icon, it seems to scale it down, and then put it in the middle with lots of white space around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740122/incorrect-icon-size-when-imported-to-exe/3740875#3740875) for some ideas. Also be sure to clean the icon cache (thumbs.db?) to see the updated icon in explorer.

Edit: [IcoFx](http://icofx.ro/) also behaved quite nicely in my tests.

Comment: I can't find a thums.db in the folder (although this would seem a likely solution)  However, re-booting the computer does appear to have fixed things.

Comment: Thumbs.db is hidden/system file so you'd need to modify your explorer view options to see it (tools - folder options - view - uncheck 'hide protected system files')

Comment: Damn, it was just a reboot! Couple of hours spent in vain... Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You must set the image dpi to 96. [**Be Aware of DPI with Image PNGs in WPF - Images Scale Weird or are Blurry**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BeAwareOfDPIWithImagePNGsInWPFImagesScaleWeirdOrAreBlurry.aspx)